# Why can I not initialize a Worksheets object variable to a Worksheets collection?

Tags: excel, vba

I understand that it's good coding habit to use object variables. 
I am trying to create an object variable called wsc that will be initialized with an object reference to the active workbook's worksheets collection. See code below.

I tried setting the object variable data type to Worksheets but it did NOT work.
It only works when I set the object variable data type to Object. 
This leads me to ask - is there a data type other than Object that will work in this case?

```
Sub FormatAllFormulas()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsc As Object   ' does not work if type is Worksheets - why?

    Set wsc = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    For Each ws In wsc
        With ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
            .Style = "Currency"
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Interior.Color = 4908260
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: In this case, unless you're using `wsc` for something other than the `For Each` loop, there really isn't a reason to hold it in a local variable. `For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` is probably better in this specific example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` returns `Sheets` not `Worksheets` so that is the type you should use.

Comment: Just for my interest: Do you know why? Is there a reason? Because this looks very strange to me if I ask for `Worksheets` and I actually get `Sheets`.

Comment: I agree, especially when ActiveWorkbook.Sheets returns Sheets.
Logically, you would expect ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets to return Worksheets.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Honestly, I don't know. I can't think of any reason for it since it only returns the Worksheets in the workbook, not any other type of sheet.

Comment: @Rory Well, thanks for the feedback, that's exactly what I thought. I can't imagine any reason too.